Setup a javascript file .js with QWebEngineView in python
I have some trouble laoding a .js file into an HTML using QWebEngineView.
this the python:
the class WebEngine_PythonTerminal() is QWebEnginePage with python console.
the function LoadCSS is used to load an external CSS file and it's working.
self.web_page = WebEngine_PythonTerminal(self)
self.web_view = QWebEngineView(self)
self.web_view.setPage(self.web_page)
self.web_view.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
self.web_view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True)

loadCSS(self, self.web_view, "HomePage/addons/main_style.css", "load_main_css")

self.web_view.page().profile().clearHttpCache()

self.web_view.page().profile().setHttpUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36")


self.channel = QWebChannel(self.web_view.page())
self.channel.registerObject("HomePage", self)  # Registra l'oggetto Qt
self.web_view.page().setWebChannel(self.channel)


# Crea un'istanza di Jinja2
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('HomePage'))
self.template = env.get_template('home_page.html')
self.html_content_main = self.template.render()


self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.web_view)
self.web_view.setHtml(self.html_content_main, baseUrl=QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.abspath("home_page.html")))

I load the js file into HTML with this
<script type="text/javascript" src="addons/main_script.js"></script
the directory three is:
-HomePage
--addons
---main_script.js
---main_style.css
--Home_page.html

i can't use the directory with, for example, C://User//...
i've searched into the site and i founded something but not for my case.
can some explain me the problem?

Those relative paths look bug-prone. What if the working directory isn't the same as the script directory? Also: Windows file-systems are usually case-insensitive, but what about urls constructed from file-paths?

can you please write some example? i'm not so good with paths. The script is inside another folder. MainApp/HomePage/Addons/main_script.js, the HTML is MainApp/HomePage/Home_page.html and the main script in in the main folder MainApp witch contains all the files and folder of the project

Get the folder of the python script with ROOTDIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)). Then use it like this: os.path.join(ROOTDIR, 'HomePage/addons/main_style.css') and QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.join(ROOTDIR, 'HomePage/Home_page.html')). Do that for all the other relative paths as well.

i've tryed something like that : ROOTDIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file))
os.path.join(ROOTDIR, 'HomePage/addons/main_style.css')
    self.web_view.setHtml(self.html_content_main, QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.join(ROOTDIR, 'HomePage/Home_page.html')),). But it's not working, the css file is not loaded. what if i have multiple file to get loaded inside the html?


If you want more help, you will have to provide a proper [mre].
